# Is it possible to configure Spark log4j2 pure programmatically?

Tags: apache-spark, log4j2

Is it possible to configure Spark log4j2 pure programmatically?
Without any "configurationFile=....log4j.properties" or XML in VM-params?
Does Spark ignore any log4j2 configuration Configurator or LogLevel e.t.c settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "Configurator or LogLevel" settings? Please add your initialization code to the question.